# Spring-data on mac. SQL queries containing a parameter with non-Latin characters returns null

Tags: java, mysql, spring, macos, hibernate

I have spring project with spring-data. I try to select my app_pages table with parameter containing Cyrillic

`long pageId = appPagesRepository.findByPageEntry("Начальный экран справки");`

on mac os this query always returns null;

`long pageId = appPagesRepository.findByPageTitle("START_HELP_SCREEN");`

this query always works correctly.

Datasource:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
    hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("sbt.db.driver.classname"));
    hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(env.getProperty("sbt.db.jdbc.url"));
    hikariConfig.setUsername(env.getProperty("sbt.db.username"));
    hikariConfig.setPassword(env.getProperty("sbt.db.password"));
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useUnicode", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.characterEncoding", "utf-8");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", "true");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
    hikariConfig.addDataSourceProperty("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", "true");
    return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Table(name="app_pages", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"id", "page_entry"})})
public class AppPagesEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, unique = true, length = 11)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "page_title", length = 60, nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String pageTitle;
    @Column(name = "page_entry", length = 60, nullable = false)
    private String pageEntry;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "uix")
    private byte[] uix;
    @Lob
    @Column(name = "image")
    private byte[] pageImage;
    @Column(name = "description", length = 500, nullable = false)
    private String description;
```

This is all that I see in the Hibernate log:

> 11:31:31.224 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select apppagesen0_.id as id1_5_, apppagesen0_.description as descript2_5_, apppagesen0_.page_entry as page_ent3_5_, apppagesen0_.image as image4_5_, apppagesen0_.page_title as page_tit5_5_, apppagesen0_.uix as uix6_5_ from mp_sbbol_pages apppagesen0_ where apppagesen0_.page_entry=?
>   11:31:31.229 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Начальный экран справки]

The database and tables are encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the result of

```
long pageId = appPagesRepository.findByPageTitle("START_HELP_SCREEN");
```

in the Hibernate log?

Maybe you misspell `[Начальный экран справки]`.